# List<Byte> to String, can you help refactor this ( small ) method?

Tags: java, arrays

We use this small utility method. But we don't like it. Since it's not very crucial (it works anyway ... ) , we have forgotten it.
But that's ugly, because we have to go through the whole array, only to convert
it from `Byte[]` to `byte[]`.
I'm looking :

- for a way to cast the `Byte[]` in `byte[]` without going through it
- or for a utility method for cast a List into string

```
public static String byteListToString(List<Byte> l, Charset charset) {
    if (l == null) {
        return "";
    }
    byte[] array = new byte[l.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Byte current : l) {
        array[i] = current;
        i++;
    }
    return new String(array, charset);
}
```

Comment: First thought... are you refering to methods as 'she'?

Comment: why not she? Ladies are the logical ones

Comment: Asker is French; French for method is 'la methode' (French being a language with gender); natural translation into English produces 'she'. I think it's amusing :) If cars and ships can traditionally be female, why not methods?

Comment: there are no elegant ways in Java to unbox an array as a whole

Comment: Haven't tested this, but does this work: new String(l.toArray(new byte[0])); ?

Comment: Yes, i'm french, i'v use "she" for the method wihout thinking to it.
I edited.
@Tim, no, it's not. Because byte[] is a primitive type.

Comment: I wonder why you use List<Byte>? What is the source of your List<Byte>?

Comment: I'd throw NPE if `l == null`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method is pretty much the only way to do it. You may find an external library that does all or part of it, but it will essentially do the same thing.

However, there is one thing in your code that is a potential problem: When calling `new String(array)`, you are using the platform default encoding to convert the bytes to characters. The platform encoding differs between operating system and locale settings - using it is almost always a bug waiting to happen. It depends on where you're getting those bytes from, but their encoding should be specified somewhere, passed as argument to the method and used for the conversion (by using the String constructor with a second parameter).

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

...

Byte[] bytes = new Byte[l.size()];
l.toArray(bytes);

byte[] b =  ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(bytes);
```

Comment: I don't think this is much of an improvement - you are adding a dependency to a 3rd party library, which internally will probably do something similar to the above code anyway.

Comment: @Jon: I partially agree - I dislike adding third party dependencies just for the odd util. method but if this dependency exists already then I think it makes the code more succinct and readable.

Comment: @Jon I too partially agree, but commons-lang is probably one of the safest third-party libraries to use, asd as Adamski says you'd probably end up using it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

without any additional library (e.g. apache commons) your method is fine

Answer (score 1):

Minor nit:

```
if (l == null || l.isEmpty() ) {
    return "" ;
}
```

to avoid creating empty Strings for empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides a number of useful [primitive utilities](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained), including a [`Bytes`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html) class which makes this and other operations on collections of `Byte`s trivial.

```
private static String toString(List<Byte> bytes) {
  return new String(Bytes.toArray(bytes), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.nio and come up with something like this

```
public static String byteListToString(List<Byte> l, Charset cs)
throws IOException
{
    final int CBUF_SIZE = 8;
    final int BBUF_SIZE = 8;

    CharBuffer cbuf = CharBuffer.allocate(CBUF_SIZE);
    char[] chArr = cbuf.array();
    ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(BBUF_SIZE);
    CharsetDecoder dec = cs.newDecoder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter((int)(l.size() * dec.averageCharsPerByte()));

    Iterator<Byte> itInput = l.iterator();
    int bytesRemaining = l.size();
    boolean finished = false;
    while (! finished)
    {
        // work out how much data we are likely to be able to read
        final int bPos = bbuf.position();
        final int bLim = bbuf.limit();
        int bSize = bLim-bPos;
        bSize = Math.min(bSize, bytesRemaining);
        while ((--bSize >= 0) && itInput.hasNext()) 
        {
            bbuf.put(itInput.next().byteValue());
            --bytesRemaining;
        }
        bbuf.flip();
        final int cStartPos = cbuf.position();
        CoderResult cr = dec.decode(bbuf, cbuf, (bytesRemaining <= 0));
        if (cr.isError()) cr.throwException();
        bbuf.compact();
        finished = (bytesRemaining <= 0) && (cr == CoderResult.UNDERFLOW);
        final int cEndPos = cbuf.position();
        final int cSize = cEndPos - cStartPos;
        sw.write(chArr, cStartPos, cSize);
        cbuf.clear();
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```

but I really don't think I'd recommend for something this simple.

Answer (score -1):

One option might be to use StringBuilder:

```
public static String byteListToString(List<Byte> l) {
    if (l == null) {
        return "" ;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(l.size());

    for (Byte current : l) {
        sb.append((char)current);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or, if you need character conversion

```
public static String byteListToString(List<Byte> l) {
    if (l == null) {
        return "" ;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(l.size());

    for (Byte current : l) {
        bout.write(current);
    }

    return bout.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

If you are aggregating bytes, try ByteArrayOutputStream in the first place instead of List of bytes. Note: Watch out for the UnsupportedEncodingException - you'll need to try-catch it somewhere.

Comment: Both snippets are much more slow and memory inefficient, compared to the one posted by OP.

Answer (score -2):

Check out the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class, I think it does what you want. Use it in combination with the List.toArray() method.

Comment: This is a java question, not .net.

Comment: It's pretty interesting though that the code looks exactly like C#. If it wasn't for the "Java" tag then there would be no way to tell. Perhaps we need a clearer way to indicate language in programming questions where there might be ambiguity.

Comment: "for (Byte current : l)" <-- not C#

Comment: You can almost always tell the difference by looking at the s in string. string = c#, String = java. :)

Comment: String would also work in .NET, it's the classname instead of the C# keyword.